# How to authenticate Paypal Success page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I have a PayPal transaction successful page that I need to store customer data on.

How can I authenticate this page on page load so that it only displays when users come back from a successful PayPal transaction? (you can't just type it in manually in the browser)

Comment: I read your question few times but stil don't understand it.

Comment: @Shoban I've given a shot at re-wording it (I knew what he meant) :)

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity, @Prisoner Yes correct.I need that my Paypal_Success_Page.aspx load only from paypal domain No one can open it manually in the browser  like  www.abc.com/Paypal_Success_Page.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you can send some custom data parameter to PayPal which PayPal sends as a parameter to  your success page. You have to check for the correct value of that parameter in your Page_load event.